# Yet another "instance has no attribute '__getitem__' " case

Tags: python, attributeerror

This seems to have been beat to death on Stack Overflow but none of the questions seem to match my problem. Anyway, straight to the code.

This is Edge.py

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
from numpy import *


class EdgeList:
    def __init__(self, mat):
        self.id1 = mat[:,0]
        self.id2 = mat[:,1]
        self.value = mat[:,2]
    def is_above(self):
        return self.value>average(self.value)
    def stats(self):
        pass #omitted; too long and irrelevant here.
```

This is AHsparse.py

```
from __future__ import division

import sys
from numpy import *
from Edge import EdgeList

class AHvector:
    def __init__(self, mat):
        self.el = EdgeList(mat)
    def multiply(self, other):
        v=zeros(max(len(self.el.val), len(other.el.val)))
        for index in self.id1:
            v[index] = self.el.val[index] * other.el.val[index]
        return v
```

This is some test code (other tests pass)

```
import sys
from numpy import *
from Edge import EdgeList
from AHsparse import AHvector

testmat =loadtxt('test.data', delimiter=';')
st = EdgeList(testmat)
stv = AHvector(st)
stv = stv.multiply(stv)
print(stv)
```

The error happens at the **init** method of class AHvector, but calls back to Edge.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/syntaxfree/Dropbox/nina/nina lives in objects/sparse_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    stv = AHvector(st)
  File "/Users/syntaxfree/Dropbox/nina/nina lives in objects/AHsparse.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.el = EdgeList(mat)
  File "/Users/syntaxfree/Dropbox/nina/nina lives in objects/Edge.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.id1 = mat[:,0]
AttributeError: EdgeList instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
```

I have nothing else to add, I'm afraid -- except I'm able to initialize EdgeList on its own and run the stats method in other test code, and I'm thoroughly confused as why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Excuse me if this is a stupid question in the context of `numpy`, but shouldn't your `EdgeList` class be a subclass of, or implement the inteface for, a class that is a `list` or other iterable?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but you supply an Edgelist as agrument (`st`) which you then try to access with `mat[:,0]` but the operator `[]` is not defined for the class `EdgeList`. @sr2222 points to a fix already

Comment: Your `EdgeList` class defines a `value` attribute, but the code that uses it tries to access `val`, which doesn't exist. This isn't the problem you're having but it's certainly another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run

```
 stv = AHvector(st)
```

`st` is an Edgelist. Then AHvector's `init` tries to make an Edgelist of `st`. Maybe AHvector should state

```
 self.el = mat # Instead of EdgeList(mat)?
```

or maybe AHvector isn't supposed to be receiving `st`, but rather `testmat`?